# How to change the date format and get date from mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, ios7, uitextfield

I am fresher to ios. i am using phpmyadmin mysql database. In that, by default it will accept date format yyyy/mm/dd. But in my application i want to get the values between two date, and their formats like mm/dd/yyyy.

I need to give input as (mm/dd/yyyy) format but database format is yyyy/mm/dd. so it is not matching and also i am getting error. Would you please help me in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting as NSString or time stamp?

Comment: First of all MySQL's default DATE field format is YYYY-MM-DD. The supported range is 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31. Check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the MYSQL function `STR_TO_DATE (string, format)`.
In your example that could be something like `STR_TO_DATE('11/13/2013, '%m/%d/%Y')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
```